# how to sort DHTMLX grid on without clicking on header

Tags: dhtml, dhtmlx

I am using DHTMLX grid on a jsp page. From server side i am loading some data on it. I want data to be in sorted manner once it is loaded on grid. I found there is method 
      `"grid.sortRows(col, type, order);"` but it works only when you click any header, i want by default data will come in sorted manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mygrid.load(YOUR_URL, function() {
    // we are in callback
    mygrid.sortRows(0, "str", "des"); // sorts grid
    mygrid.setSortImgState(true, 0, "des"); // sets icon to sort arrow
});
```